# eclipse: synchronize project's lib with maven's repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, repository, lib

I just want to make sure that the jars in the lib folder of the project are always the same as the jars that are found in my local maven repository. In case I bring new things in the repository via `mvn dependency:sources` (ran in cmd), I want to make sure that no older versions are still in my lib.

Two sub-questions:

1. how to manually perform the action of bringing jars from the repository to the project?
2. how to configure eclipse to automatically perform this synchronization action?

setup details: I have a folder called repository, which is referenced by the `<localRepository>` tag in the *settings.xml*. In eclipse I refer the *settings.xml* file via Window/Preferences/Maven/User Settings, so eclipse sees my repository.

I have no maven plugin installed in eclipse.

Comment: Why do you need a lib folder in the project? Usually, Maven projects do not need this.

Comment: there is a lib folder containing some jars. It is a legacy project. I just inherited it this way

Comment: So what is this lib folder for? Do you really need it?

Comment: I cannot delete it. It would impact all other people working on the project.

Comment: I am just saying: You are trying to manage jars inside project folders. This is Ant style and usually unnecessary in Maven. You are putting effort into doing this regardless. You must have a reason for that. If the reason is "it was always there and I don't know what it is for", this is a bad reason.